# Is there a git command that can resolve an error: remote branch 'refs/heads/foo/bar' not found?

Tags: git, fetch, pull, refspec

In my situation I was tracking a remote hotfix branch which someone else merged and removed.

I have deleted my local branch but when I pull I still get the above error because I have the following lines in my git config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
...
    fetch = +refs/heads/foo/bar:refs/remotes/origin/foo/bar
    push = +refs/heads/foo/bar:refs/for/foo/bar
...
```

The error can be resolved by deleting these lines from the file but is there a way to do it from the command line?

Comment: git remote prune origin does not resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, but it's generally a lot more difficult than manual editing, if you want to get rid of just the one matching line.

The command to modify a git configuration file is [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  It has `--unset`, `--unset-all`, and `--remove-section` options for deleting one, all matching, or all entries in some particular section or key.

The section, in this case, is `remote.origin` (because it's in `[remote "origin"]` in the file) and the key is `remote.origin.fetch`.  You would not want to remove the entire section, in this case, so that leaves `--unset` and `--unset-all` as possibilities.

There can be more than one `fetch` line, and more than one `push` line.  In other words there can be multiple copies of one key, with different values.

If there is just one `remote.origin.fetch` line, and you want to remove it, you can simply:

```
git config --unset remote.origin.fetch
```

If you try this on a repository with *multiple* fetch lines, you get:

```
warning: remote.origin.fetch has multiple values
```

and you will find that nothing is removed (at least that is what I got with git 2.1.0).  In this case, you need the more complex variants, either `--unset-all` (remove *all* the `remote.origin.fetch` keys) or `--unset key value_regex` (remove those keys whose value matches *`value_regex`*).

Since you presumably only want to unset the one matching line, you must come up with a regular expression that matches that one line, and only that one line.  Read through [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) to come up with a suitable regular expression; note that since these are POSIX "extended" REs, a bare `+` character means "one or more of the previous character", so `+refs/...` does not work as the "previous character" part is missing.  (These are also clearly un-anchored, based on the documentation.)  In this case, `:refs/remotes/origin/foo/bar` is probably sufficient, but you could get fancier.

To remove the `push` entry, repeat the above steps but with `remote.origin.push` as the key.

(Or just use your favorite editor and interactively delete the right lines, which is a lot easier, albeit not very suitable for a script...)